# Hibernate delete order not mainatining

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

On delete i am deleting records from multiple tables. 
I have two tables .job_execution and job. Now i want to delete job so first i have to delete job_execution.

job_execution has mapping to job table.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
private Job job;
```

Now i am deleteing

```
jobExecutionRepository.delete(jobExecution);
jobRepository.delete(job);
```

But i am getting ERROR: update or delete on table "job" violates foreign key constraint "job_execution_job_id_fkey" on table "job_execution".

I also checked sql queries and i found out jobExecutionRepository delete query is not executed. It directly called  jobRepository delete query.

Comment: It is due to foreign key. If you delete parent table it doesn't allowed to delete because child table contains the some id of parent table. If you want to do so then you can use `on delete cascade` that delete the respective data from child table too

Comment: Yes. but i am deleting child first by jobExecutionRepository.delete(jobExecution);

Comment: can you post your database structure

Comment: are the two deletes in the same transaction?

Comment: Have you deleted all the child of parent table (of that particular id) before deleting job

Comment: yea.all in same transaction. using class level transaction. and deleting all child. i checked that.

Comment: Does it work when you flush the context in between the two calls?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must program in managed environment and so each session run in a transaction in database level.

Delete in hibernate apply in database when `session closed` or `session flush`.
Therefore as you said when you have child/parent relation like this; you must delete children first.But queries apply and commit when session flushed.

So you must  handle it yourself and **flush or close session**  just after delete children.

Or if you have bidirectional relation and in parent entity have set of children. You can use `cascade.remove` or `cascade.delete` on set to hibernate manage it automatically.